# PrimeNG Treetable childnode post expand event

Tags: angular, primeng, treetable

We've requirement where the parent element with checkbox and then expandable child nodes need to have radio buttons, as treetable only has support for checkbox, we've injected dynamic HTML for checkbox and radio buttons required, issue is whenever we expand or collapse child node all the radio buttons and checkbox selections are getting cleared, we've the list of the selected items in an array, so we are fine to loop through but even if we are trying to loop through the list in nodeexpand event still the selections are getting cleared, please help me in getting a solution on how i can maintain the state of the checkbox and radio buttons binded to innerHTML property even after node expand or collapse

```
 <p-treeTable [value]="gridData" [columns]="scrollableColumns" [frozenColumns]="frozenCols" [scrollable]="true" frozenWidth="150px">
    <ng-template pTemplate="colgroup" let-columns>
      <colgroup>
        <col *ngFor="let col of columns" style="width:250px;">
      </colgroup>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let col of columns;let i =index" style="height:47px !important">
          <div *ngIf="col.field.toUpperCase() == 'SNO'" [innerHTML]="col.header | sanitizeHtml: 'html'" style="width:100px !important">
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="col.field.toUpperCase() != 'SNO'">
            {{col.header}}
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData="rowData" let-columns="columns">
      <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let col of columns; let i = index">
          <div *ngIf="col.field.toUpperCase() == 'CURRENTDNBCOMPANYNAME'" (click)="showDialog()">
            <a class="cusror">{{rowData[col.field]}}</a>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="col.field.toUpperCase() != 'CURRENTDNBCOMPANYNAME'">
            {{rowData[col.field]}}
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="frozenbody" let-rowNode let-rowData="rowData">
      <tr style="width:100px !important">
        <td style="display:-webkit-inline-box;width:100% !important;">
          <p-treeTableToggler class="{{rowData.class}}" [rowNode]="rowNode"></p-treeTableToggler>
          <div [innerHTML]="rowData.Sno | sanitizeHtml: 'html'"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
  </p-treeTable>
```

IN typescript

this.gridData = [
  {
    data: { class: 'abc', Sno: '', RecommendationSource: 'DMS', CityofRecommendedDNB: 'Redmond', RecommendedDnB: 'Core American Security', CurrentDNBCompanyName: 'ACADEMIE DE PARIS', LegalEntityCompanyName: 'Microsoft Corp.', CID: 'ebf1bd3b-37cb-4fdc-a463-fad6b8bb5d68', DNBID: '392085739', Address: 'France', City: '94 AVENUE GAMBETTA    ' },
    expanded: true,
    children: [
      {
        data: { Sno: '', RecommendationSource: 'DMS - City: PARIS', CityofRecommendedDNB: 'Jarvis', RecommendedDnB: 'Core American Security', CurrentDNBCompanyName: 'Académie de Paris', LegalEntityCompanyName: 'Microsoft Corp.', CID: 'ebf1bd3b-37cb-4fdc-a463-fad6b8bb5d68', DNBID: '392085733', Address: 'France', City: '94 avenue GAMBETTA' },
      },
      {
        data: { Sno: '', RecommendationSource: 'Jarvis', CityofRecommendedDNB: 'Bellevue', RecommendedDnB: 'Core American Security', CurrentDNBCompanyName: 'Microsoft', LegalEntityCompanyName: 'Microsoft Corp.', CID: 'ebf1bd3b-37cb-4fdc-a463-fad6b8bb5d68', DNBID: '234423423', Address: 'U.S', City: 'GAMBETTA' },
        children: [
          {
            data: { Sno: '', RecommendationSource: 'DMS', CityofRecommendedDNB: 'Seattle', RecommendedDnB: 'Core American Security', CurrentDNBCompanyName: 'Académie de Paris', LegalEntityCompanyName: 'Microsoft Corp.', CID: 'ebf1bd3b-37cb-4fdc-a463-fad6b8bb5d68', DNBID: '4234234234', Address: 'france', City: 'japan' },
          },
          {
            data: { Sno: '', RecommendationSource: 'DMS', CityofRecommendedDNB: 'Everret', RecommendedDnB: 'ACADEMIE DE PARIS', CurrentDNBCompanyName: 'Core American Security', LegalEntityCompanyName: '94 avenue', CID: 'ebf1bd3b-37cb-4fdc-a463-fad6b8bb5d68', DNBID: '353534', Address: 'japan', City: 'austin' },
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    data: { class: 'abc', Sno: '', RecommendationSource: 'DMS', CityofRecommendedDNB: 'Redmond', RecommendedDnB: 'Core American Security', CurrentDNBCompanyName: 'Microsoft', LegalEntityCompanyName: 'Microsoft Corp.', CID: '211fc80e-6d4b-4605-998b-b75945ff22f1', DNBID: '650558641', Address: 'Chalfont', City: 'Pittsburgh' },
    expanded: true,
    children: [
      {
        data: { Sno: '', RecommendationSource: 'DMS', CityofRecommendedDNB: 'Bellevue', RecommendedDnB: 'Core American Security', CurrentDNBCompanyName: 'Microsoft', LegalEntityCompanyName: 'Microsoft Corp.', CID: '211fc80e-6d4b-4605-998b-b75945ff22f1', DNBID: '456783', Address: 'Jarvis', City: 'My data health' },
        children: [
          {
            data: { Sno: '', RecommendationSource: 'DMS', CityofRecommendedDNB: 'BELLEAVUE', RecommendedDnB: 'Core American SECURITY', CurrentDNBCompanyName: 'Microsoft', LegalEntityCompanyName: 'Microsoft Corp.', CID: '211fc80e-6d4b-4605-998b-b75945ff22f1', DNBID: '45678356', Address: 'Chalfont', City: 'Pittsburgh' },
          },
          {
            data: { Sno: '', RecommendationSource: 'Jarvis', CityofRecommendedDNB: 'Everret', RecommendedDnB: 'Core American Security', CurrentDNBCompanyName: 'Microsoft', LegalEntityCompanyName: 'Microsoft Corp.', CID: '211fc80e-6d4b-4605-998b-b75945ff22f1', DNBID: '45678356', Address: 'Pittsburgh', City: 'Chalfont' },
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

Comment: post code and stackbliz please

Comment: Added Patricio, please let me know if you need anything